# How to initiate chef-client command from a recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am running a recipe which has the following resource

```
execute 'bootstrap' do
  command 'chef-client -j /etc/chef/prod/first-boot.json'
end
```

As you can see I am trying to run another chef-client command from within another chef-client run. How can achieve this. This is the requirement so I cannot change how this resource works.

Comment: Please don't cross post to the mailing list and here. It just means the volunteer support team has to answer in both. If you don't get a response after a few days in one or other, it's cool, but you did it simultaneously.

Comment: sure will keep in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answered on the Chef mailing list. This is not supported.